# using source in a bash script

Tags: perl, bash, env, perlbrew

I've installed some of my code that needs Perl 5.010 on a CentOS 5.x server using perlbrew and it needs the two lines

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

and

```
perlbrew switch perl-5.10.1
```

To be executed in the shell before I have perl 5.010 in my /usr/bin/env, so I tried to create the following executable bash script to minimise these two steps to `./setEnv.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "**setting environment variables - 'perlbrew switch-off' to exit"
SETSOURCE= `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc`
echo $SETSOURCE
SETPERL= `perlbrew switch perl-5.10.1`
echo $SETPERL
```

Comment: Syntax note: Your assignments do nothing because you have whitespace between the variable assignment and the command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

A process can't modify its parent environment, so you are doing it wrong since the shebang.

Doing a source in a backtick (subshell) only affects the subshell, and it ends after the command execution.

```
    $ ### test.sh assign "inside" to TEST
    $ TEST='outside'; echo "$(source test.sh; echo $TEST)" - $TEST
    inside - outside
```

What you probably want to do is source your `setEnv.sh` script directly from your shell.

```
    $ ### test.sh assign "inside" to TEST
    $ TEST='outside'; source test.sh; echo $TEST 
    inside
```

Comment: Why can't I press the enter key and have it insert a line break in your comment form? Chrome/Ubuntu12.04 ?? That's not cool.

Comment: @user1439590 because, AFAIK, we can't do multi-line comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `source` command without backticks. Just write a line

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

in your script. (`source` has side-effects, which doesn't work when you are in a sub-shell. I'm not even sure you can run `source` as an external command.)

Comment: I'd recommend removing the last paragraph and add it as a comment. It's not part of the answer. And probably other SOers/visits don't need a lecture about how to ask questions, even if i totally agree too, upvoting David's comment would work too..